# What would cause the @Activate method to not be invoked for Apache Felix?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have an Apache Felix component who's definition looks like this:

```
...
@Component(immediate=true)

@Service
public class myClass implements myClassInterface {
    ...
    @Activate
    public void activate(final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        //Do activation stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

From reading the Apache Felix documentation on the `@Component` and `@Activate` annotations (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#component) I understand that the `immediate=true` attribute for the `@Component` is "activated immediately". My problem is that my `activate` method never seems to be invoked. I have my debugger on from the moment I build my project until the moment I request the service `myClass` using OSGi, but the `activate` method never seems to be invoked.

So, my question has a few layers:
1. Telling me that `immediate=true` attribute causes the component to be "activated immediately" doesn't give me enough information. Does this mean that the component is activated immediately after the project is built, immediately after an instance of `myClass` is created, or immediately after the service `myClass` is requested by the OSGi bundle?
2. Is there anything that might cause my `activate` method to not be invoked in spite of my usage of `immediate=true`? If so, what can I do to correct the issue?

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 4):

Immediate=false means the component is only activated once it is requested by another component. Immediate=true means it is activated once all its mandatory references are present.

So if your component is not activated then maybe a service it needs is not present. You can look into the status of the components by using the scr commands in the gogo shell.

Another thing is to define what interface to publish the service with. I am not sure about the felix SCR annotations but with DS annotations you need to set @Component(service=myClass.class) if the class does not implement any interface.

Btw. You should switch to the standard DS annotations. See http://enroute.osgi.org/doc/217-ds.html. The felix ones are deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I didn't see any information in the Felix documentation suggesting that the annotations were deprecated. Given that a component won't be activated until its required services are present, I think I know what I can do to start debugging. How do I know which references are mandatory for a given component?

Comment: You need to check in the DS spec or documentation I linked. By default @Reference is mandatory.